# How do I return a value from a method in Spring Integration and not interrupt the original Message flow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

The `encode` method of the `fileProcessor` bean is responsible for encoding a video file.  If it encounters a problem the file should not be deleted, otherwise if everything is well, it is okay to delete.  Right now, the only way to preserve the `Message` flow without changing the payload is to make the `encode` method return `void`.  I need to return some 'header' information though so that `SI` can later delete the file.  I tried using `MessageBuilder` to create a `Message<File>` and return that, but when it arrives in the next channel it has been wrapped and there is a `Message` inside a `Message`, therefore my expression doesn't work to trigger the delete.

I suppose I could use a wrapped `Message` and dig down one level in the object graph, but that seems clunky.

What is the best approach to tacking on some return value without destroying the original Message payload and without polluting my POJO encode method with SI channels and sending?

Here is my configuration:

```
<!-- ########################## -->
<!-- ###      Encoding      ### -->
<!-- ########################## -->

<file:inbound-channel-adapter 
    directory="${paths.encode}"
    channel="encodeChannel"
    filename-regex="${encode.regex}"
    prevent-duplicates="false">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator
    input-channel="encodeChannel"
    output-channel="encodeResultChannel"
    ref="fileProcessor"
    method="encode">
</int:service-activator>    

<!-- This is where I'm having trouble.  -->
<!-- I don't expect this router to work. -->
<int:router
    input-channel="encodeResultChannel"
    expression="payload">       
    <int:mapping value="true" channel="encodeDeleteChannel"/>
    <int:mapping value="false" channel="stdout"/>
</int:router>

<int:service-activator
    input-channel="encodeDeleteChannel"
    expression="payload.delete()"
    output-channel="stdout">
</int:service-activator>

<stream:stdout-channel-adapter 
    id="stdout" 
    append-newline="true" />
```

edit:

I'm using:

```
<properties>
    <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

edit2:

here's the updated configuration

```
<!-- ########################## -->
<!-- ###      Encoding      ### -->
<!-- ########################## -->

<file:inbound-channel-adapter 
    directory="${paths.encode}"
    channel="filePickupChannel"
    filename-regex="${encode.regex}"
    prevent-duplicates="false">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:header-enricher
    input-channel="filePickupChannel"
    output-channel="encodeChannel">
    <int:header name="origFile" expression="payload"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<int:service-activator
    input-channel="encodeChannel"
    output-channel="encodeResultChannel"
    ref="fileProcessor"
    method="encode">
</int:service-activator>    

<int:router
    input-channel="encodeResultChannel"
    ignore-send-failures="false"
    default-output-channel="stdout"
    expression="payload">       
    <int:mapping value="true" channel="encodeDeleteChannel"/>
    <int:mapping value="false" channel="stdout"/>
</int:router>

<int:service-activator
    input-channel="encodeDeleteChannel"
    expression="headers['origFile'].delete()"
    output-channel="stdout">
</int:service-activator>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Spring Integration and Spring Framework are you using?

What does the signature of `fileProcessor.encode()` look like?

You should not get a nested `Message<?>`, the `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` has the following logic...

```
private Message<?> createReplyMessage(Object reply, MessageHeaders requestHeaders) {
    AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<?> builder = null;
    if (reply instanceof Message<?>) {
        if (!this.shouldCopyRequestHeaders()) {
            return (Message<?>) reply;
        }
        builder = this.getMessageBuilderFactory().fromMessage((Message<?>) reply);
    }

...

    if (this.shouldCopyRequestHeaders()) {
        builder.copyHeadersIfAbsent(requestHeaders);
    }
    return builder.build();
}
```

So, if you return a `Message<?>` your message is returned (enhanced with any inbound headers that you didn't set).

Are you using Spring Integration 3.0.x with Spring Framework 4.0.x? If so, you need to be careful to return an `org.springframework.integration` Message, not an `org.springframework.messaging` message.

If you return an `org.springframework.messaging` Message, Spring Integration will indeed wrap it in a Spring Integration Message.

Core messaging classes were moved to the `spring-messaging` module in Spring Framework 4.0, so they can be used for websockets, STOMP etc.

Spring Integration 4.0.x now uses those classes as well so you won't see both on the classpath; avoiding the confusion. When using Spring Integration 3.0.x with Spring Framework 4.0.x, you need to take great care to use the right classes.

In general, however, we don't recommend adding framework classes (such as `Message<?>`) to your code, use POJOs instead, and the framework will take care of the messaging details...

```
boolean encode(File file) {...}
```

If you need to access the payload after the encode, consider promoting it to a header beforehand.

```
<int:header-enricher ...>
    <int:header name="origFile" expression="payload" />
</int:header-enricher>
```

Then use `expression="headers['origFile'].delete()` after the encode.

EDIT:

Or, return the file (so it becomes the new payload) on success and, on failure, return `null` or throw an exception and the downstream flow won't be executed.

Comment: I was returning an org.springframework.messaging Message when encountering a wrapped message.  Changing it to org.springframework.integration did result in the desired behavior as you describe.  I do prefer your suggestion though to use a POJO and that is what I was trying to accomplish in the first place.  I was unaware of this usage of the header-enricher (still learning).  This now works as expected, thank you very much for sharing this solution.

Comment: Here's the new message... 18:51:41.373 [task-scheduler-5] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'encodeDeleteChannel', message: [Payload=true][Headers={timestamp=1401144701371, id=107b6f6b-c925-deb0-a2a5-7f1dbd2357a8, origFile=C:\share\datagator\encode\test video.mpg}]